# How can I check if a PDF contains vector images?

Tags: pdf, vector

A general method is fine but if the PDF version is important, it's 1.6.

Comment: In general, a PDF *is* a vector image that spans multiple pages.  You can check whether it contains raster images, or you can check to see if it contains certain drawing commands, but I suspect you'll get a lot of false positives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% of PDF's contain vector information.
If you'd like to check on a certain element within a PDF just zoom in really really close.

If you are wanting to do this programmatically then you haven't specified to us that point.